# Dynamic Folder SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I am creating a package that goes through a few folder paths and loads excel files. The file paths for the excel files are as follows. The files are located in "a" folder which is named the same from year to year, however, the "xy*" folder name changes depending on the year. So I want SSIS to look for the excel files by searching through the H drive that has the "a" folder. I looked at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(string, string,SearchOptions) but that only gives me the first subfolder. for instance H:\x\xy2017. any help is much appreciated.

H:\x\xy2017\z\xy2017\a

H:\x\xy2017\z\xy2017\a

H:\x\xy2018\z\xy2018\a

This is the C# code I used in Script task to recursively loop through the folders. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
        Dts.Variables["User::varFolderPath1"].Value = Directory.GetFiles(@"S:\HEDIS", "*DMHM Lead Results*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (Object obj in Dts.Variables["User::varFolderPath1"].Value.ToString())
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Dts.Variables["User::varFolderPath1"].Value.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: To restate, given a starting directory, I'd like to generate a list of all the folders that are named a specific value.

Comment: @billinkc yes, I am trying to have a list of folder paths that contain that specific folder name. Thanks

Comment: Tried calling your method recursively?

Comment: @dsdel yes I did but what that it doesn't seem to bring any results

Comment: @Hmen please update yoru post containing the code of what you tried

Comment: @dsdel i have updated the post. Thanks

Comment: @Hmen is there a maximum depth of directories (as in each directory can at maximum 3 times contain your search string)? Does the drive contain many files? If not, perhaps finding all files is a better choice?

Comment: @dsdel yes the directories are gonna have the same level as specified in the example and there are a lot of other excel files in that root folder so I don't want to bring all the files.

Comment: @Hmem tried putting foreach in foreach? This way, you can search the received directory for all other directories below finding what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script task answer.

```
  string root = @"S:\directory\";
        string folder = "root folder";
        DateTime lookbackDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);

        string messageText = "";

        messageText += String.Format("We're looking for files that have been made since {0}", lookbackDate);
        MessageBox.Show(messageText); messageText += "\n";
        messageText += ("Starting directory search now\n");
        MessageBox.Show(messageText); messageText += "\n";

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(root, folder, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            messageText += String.Format("Directory found! {0}", dir);
            MessageBox.Show(messageText); messageText += "\n";

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                DateTime filedate = File.GetCreationTime(file);
                string fname = Path.GetFileName(file);

                if (filedate >= lookbackDate)
                {
                    messageText += String.Format("MATCH! {0} - created {1}", fname, filedate);
                    MessageBox.Show(messageText); messageText += "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    messageText += String.Format("TOO OLD! {0} - created {1}", fname, filedate);
                    MessageBox.Show(messageText); messageText += "\n";
                }

            }
        }

        messageText += ("\nDirectory search complete!");
        MessageBox.Show(messageText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Foreach Loop Container".

1 Go to "Collection" and choose the "Foreach File Enumerator".

2 It will ask for the folder that contains the files, here you have to choose your Main folder

ie in your case  (H:\x).

3 Then you need to check the "**Traverse subfolders**" checkbox and that should do it.

[image]

Comment: thank you but the naming of the excel files change as well and there are multiple excel files in the root.

Comment: in files put        *.xls or what ever extension .this will give all file in sub folder  having extension.xls

Comment: Thanks for your input but there are a lot of excel files in that root folder I don't want so your way will also try to load those files and the package will fail.